# Speeding up solving many coupled non-linear differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, performance-tuning

I am currently working on a project that involves solving many coupled non-linear ODEs$^*$ I am using NDSolveValue and the time it takes to solve everything is (understandably) slow. But I was wondering if there is anything I can do to at least make things go faster than they are now.

I have tried reducing the number of decimal places my parameters have. I have also needed to add in the option

```
"Method" -> {"EquationSimplification" -> {Automatic, 
"TimeConstraint" -> 100}
```

so that I wouldn't get an error about how Mathematica handles the equations.

For certain situations the solutions do become oscillatory, so I don't want to have to lose to much precision in the solution to speed up the solving time.

I am fairly new to some of this more "in-depth" differential equation solving methods, so if I need to give more information please let me know.

---

$^*$For more context, I am simulating things dealing with cells in a tissue. Each cell has its own set of coupled differential equations, and then some of these equations are also coupled between cells. The largest amount of cells I have been dealing with is around 4,800, where each cell has 11 differential equations (and of course 11 initial conditions).